# PHP obtener resultado de un PROCEDURE Sql Server

Tags: php, sql-server

Hola estoy tratando de obtener un valor de un procedimiento almacenado con php pero no logro obtener el resultado del PA.

PROCEDURE:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[JSP_GetNextAutonumber](@Type VARCHAR(20))
AS
WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @Nbr VARCHAR(50);
    UPDATE Auto_number SET  @Nbr = Last_Nbr += 1 WHERE Type = @Type

    IF  @Type = 'SalesOrder'BEGIN
        IF  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SO_Header WHERE Sales_Order = @Nbr) BEGIN
            SELECT @Nbr
            return @Nbr;
        END
    END ELSE IF @Type = 'PurchaseOrder' BEGIN
        IF  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PO_Header WHERE PO = @Nbr) BEGIN
            SELECT @Nbr
            return @Nbr;
        END
    END ELSE IF @Type = 'Packlist' BEGIN
        IF  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Packlist_Header WHERE Packlist = @Nbr) BEGIN
            SELECT @Nbr
            return @Nbr;
        END
    END ELSE IF @Type = 'Invoice' BEGIN
        IF  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Invoice_Header WHERE Document = @Nbr) BEGIN
            SELECT @Nbr
            return @Nbr;
        END
    END
END
```

PHP

```
$serverName = "LAPTOP-5HT35E0A\SQLEXPRESS"; 
$uid = "sa";   
$pwd = "123";  
$databaseName = "Alkon_Prod"; 

$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                         "Database"=>$databaseName); 

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */  
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  
$procedure_params = array("Packlist");
$tsql = "EXEC JSP_GetNextAutonumber @Type = ?;";  

/* Execute the query. */  
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $tsql, $procedure_params);

if( !$stmt ) {
     echo (sqlsrv_errors());      
}
               
$result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
if ( !$result ) {
     echo Exception(sqlsrv_errors(), 0);
}


 $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ;
  
echo "Col1: ".$row[0]."\n";  
echo "-----------------<br>\n";  
  

/* Free statement and connection resources. */  
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

Resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en Sql MS si sale el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

********************************EDIT********************************_____

Tuve que cambiar el SP PARA que acepte el parametro out

```
CREATE or alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[JSP_GetNextAutonumber2](@Type VARCHAR(20), @Salida VARCHAR(50) OUT)
AS
WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @Nbr VARCHAR(50);
    UPDATE Auto_number SET  @Nbr = Last_Nbr += 1 WHERE Type = @Type

    IF  @Type = 'SalesOrder'BEGIN
        IF  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SO_Header WHERE Sales_Order = @Nbr) BEGIN
            SET @Salida = @Nbr;
            break;
        END
    END ELSE IF @Type = 'PurchaseOrder' BEGIN
        IF  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PO_Header WHERE PO = @Nbr) BEGIN
            SET @Salida = @Nbr;
            break;
        END
    END ELSE IF @Type = 'Packlist' BEGIN
        IF  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Packlist_Header WHERE Packlist = @Nbr) BEGIN
            SET @Salida = @Nbr;
            break;
        END
    END ELSE IF @Type = 'Invoice' BEGIN
        IF  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Invoice_Header WHERE Document = @Nbr) BEGIN
            SET @Salida = @Nbr;
            break;
        END
    END
END
```

Y sigue saliendo vacío.

Resultado

**string(8000) "" Col1: -----------------**

Answer (score 0):

Según el [ejemplo de la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-output-parameters-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) conviene usar la forma canónica para llamar a tu SP.

Además, debes indicar de qué tipo son los parámetros, y si alguno es de salida, debes pasarlo por referencia usando `&`, para poder obtener la respuesta a posteriori en la variable que hayas indicado.

También he organizado los `if` de una forma lógica. En tu código actual por ejemplo si el `prepare` fallaba seguía luego hacia la línea que hacía el `execute`, lo cual no tiene sentido.

Intenta así:

```
  $serverName = "LAPTOP-5HT35E0A\SQLEXPRESS"; 
  $uid = "sa";   
  $pwd = "123";  
  $databaseName = "Alkon_Prod"; 

  $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                           "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                           "Database"=>$databaseName); 

  /* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */  
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
  /*
     Mucho OJO a esta parte, lee lo que dice la doc en el enlace
  */  
  $paramIn="Packlist";
  $paramOut="";
  $procedure_params = array(
                             array($paramIn, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),  
                             array(&$paramOut, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)  
                            );
  $tsql = "{call JSP_GetNextAutonumber (?, ?)}";  

  /* Execute the query. */  
  if ($stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $tsql, $procedure_params)) {
    if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
      
          /*
              OJO también a esto, en las SP no se usan los métodos fetch
              Los datos quedan vinculados a la variable que indicaste 
              como parámetro de salida con SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT
          */

          #For test only
          var_dump($paramOut);
            
          echo "Col1: ".$paramOut."\n";  
          echo "-----------------<br>\n"; 
          /* Free statement and connection resources. */  
          sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
                 
    } else {
      echo Exception(sqlsrv_errors(), 0);
    }
  } else {
       echo (sqlsrv_errors());      
  }
                 
  sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder pero sigue sin salir el resultado del SP :(, ya actualicé mi pregunta.

Comment: Hola @JorgeLuis, la salida sugiere que hay una cadena con 8,000 caracteres. Puede que no veas los resultados por otros motivos. Ponlo así y dinos si ves algo: `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($paramOut); echo "</pre>;"`

Comment: Perdon por tardar en contestar cuando pongo var_dump($paramOut) me sale string(8000)

Comment: Ponlo entre `<pre>` y `</pre>` como te indiqué en el anterior comentario, para ver qué es lo que hay, el 8000 sugiere una cadena de 8000 caracteres.

Comment: Salio asi string(8000) ""